# Meaning of the expression "left of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I can't figure out what the expression "pretty left of" means in the following context

> If you know my shtick, you know, hypocritically or not, I talk a game pretty left of "you work at McDonalds so you suck". Unintended angle.

It's a tweet and this is the [link](https://twitter.com/danharmon/status/917955464511361024) (second comment)

Has left a political meaning, or is it literally left?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this as political. In U.S. politics left is generally synonymous with liberal and right is conservative

The context, from what I understand, is the typically right-wing 'Pull yourself up by your bootstraps' philosophy. It essentially asserts that everyone has the opportunity to succeed if they work hard enough. If someone is not successful, then they must be lazy.

Since he's talking 'a game pretty left of' that, the author is saying that he has a more liberal interpretation. The implication is that he knows not only lazy/stupid people work at McDonalds and believes the issue is more nuanced than that and that something previously stated is being taken out of context or misinterpreted.